# How to connect to Mesos cluster via Java program?

Tags: java, mesos

I know that I can create framework and scheduler using Mesos API and submit tasks via Java program.

I have a different requirement. I want to know the active/inactive frameworks, executors and container information via Java program. I have a single node apache mesos on which I am running Spark jobs. I am able to see the job details on the web UI of apache mesos. The dirty way is to scrap the web page and fetch the data, but I am looking for an elegant solution by using mesos Java API.

Answer (score 0):

To get the snapshot of the Mesos cluster's state, query the Master's /state.json endpoint.

Comment: Actually I did that and I can fetch list of json items. But I am looking for slave's state.json end-point. I am not able to find the REST API URL pattern for slave's state.json end-point.

Comment: Mesos slave has /state.json endpoint as well: by default a slave listens on 5051

Answer (score 0):

you need to set --port equal to 5051 while running slave instance and then slave REST APIs are working. For details, refer following URLs,
for master => http://localhost:5050/help
for slave => http://localhost:5051/help